# Can multi-Book Memoir-class documents forgo Parts without breaking bookmarks?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, bookmarks

I wish to create a multi-Book Memoir-class document without the need for Part sections. Doing so breaks the bookmarks appearing in the PDF document. E.g., if I have a document such as

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\book{Book1}
 %\part{Part1}
  \chapter{Chapter1}
  \chapter{Chapter2}
  \chapter{Chapter3}
\end{document}
```

the PDF's "chapter" bookmarks are structured like

- Book1

  - Chapter1

    - Charper2
    - Charper3

instead of the expected

- Book1

  - Chapter1
  - Charper2
  - Charper3

I noticed that by uncommenting the Part section in the above MWE, the chapter bookmarks are correctly structured:

- Book1

  - Part1

    - Charper1
    - Charper2
    - Charper3

Is there a way to forgo Parts and still get properly indented "chapter" bookmarks?

Comment: Is your MWE complete? Memoir does not add bookmarks by default – people usually get them with packages such as `hyperref` or `bookmark`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I add the `hyperref` package to your MWE, the new bookmark structure is wrong indeed:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\book{Book1}
 %\part{Part1}
  \chapter{Chapter1}
  \chapter{Chapter2}
  \chapter{Chapter3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The solution is to load the [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) package:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\book{Book1}
 %\part{Part1}
  \chapter{Chapter1}
  \chapter{Chapter2}
  \chapter{Chapter3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does it! Thank you. Note that Bookmark fixes things, regardless if Hyperref is used or not.